# Control windows command prompt via tcl

Tags: tcl

I am launching command prompt as:
`eval exec [auto_execok start] &`

It returns me the pid, and launches command prompt.
Can I control the launched shell? Or is there any other way.

Right now I am sending command at the time of launch like:
`eval exec [auto_execok start] "cd Desktop" &`

But I want to control the shell for further operations.

Comment: You should use `Expect` for interactive CLI sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control anything launched that way (other than whatever you can do with the pid); it's specifically requesting to have no control at all with the `&` at the end.

Some programs can be controlled somewhat when they are launched as pipelines.

```
set pipeline [open |cmd "r+"]
fconfigure $pipeline -buffering line -blocking 0
puts $pipeline "dir"
while {![fblocked $pipeline]} {
    set line [gets $pipeline]
    puts "I have read: $line"
}
```

Even more control can be done via Expect, an extension package.

However, the command prompt window can't be controlled by either of these mechanisms; most programs that open windows can't.

Comment: I'm using "&" b'coz without it I'm not getting the tcl prompt back.

Comment: Yes. With `exec` without `&`, Tcl waits for the subprocess to finish before continuing. With a terminal prompt, that might take some time!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're trying to reinvent a batch file the hard way.

If you need to perform a series of tasks using `cmd.exe`, spawn it using

```
set cmd [open |cmd.exe "r+"]
```

and then simply write your batch script to that stream:

```
puts $cmd $myscript
```

To explain: shells (Tcl's own `tclsh` and `wish` included) usually have two modes of execution: interactive and non-interactive.  The fisrt is enabled when the shell is started "as is", the second—when it's started in a pipeline<sup>1</sup>.  In interactive mode, the shell would display you its prompt and accept commands—interactively.
In a non-interactive mode, it will just read commands on its [standard input stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) and execute them as it reads them.
The `cmd.exe` of Windows is no exception, so you can `open |cmd.exe` it in "read/write" mode (`r+`) and write the script composed in its batch command language to its standard input stream which will be bound to the stream object `open` returns.

If a process started with `open` or `exec` writes anything to its standard *error* stream and/or quits with a non-zero exit code, those commands will raise an exception (that is, error handling is mostly covered for you).

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, for Windows, it's harder to define what "interactive" vs "non-interactive" means, but it's somewhat irrelevant to the question at hand.